# How can i test not creation of a service?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i want to test if the object was created or not, for this case is 'create section error'

```
context 'create section error' do
    subject(:created) do
      described_class.call(name: 'obj1').result
    end
    it 'case 1' do
      expect(created).to be_empty
    end
  end
```

i am getting this error

```
Failure/Error: expect(section_created).to be_empty
       expected #<Section id: nil, name: "obj1" created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> to respond to `empty?`
```

section have `id: nil`

Comment: I tried to answer the question but you should really define what Service means in this context and what you mean by "if the object was created or not" means. Do you mean that you're want to test if a model is inserted into the database?

Answer (score 0):

If the object is an ActiveRecord model you can use the [change matchers](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/change-matcher) together with a count of the database rows:

```
it "creates a FooBar" do
  expect do
    described_class.call(name: 'obj1')
  end.to change(FooBar, :count).by(1)
end

it "does not create a FooBar" do
  expect do
    described_class.call(name: 'not a valid value')
  end.to_not change(FooBar, :count)
end
```

The does a count before and after the block is executed.

If `described_class.call(name: 'obj1')` returns an instance of a model you can also check if it has been `persisted?` instead of testing the side effects:

```
it 'case 1' do
  expect(created.persisted?).to be_false
end
```